# Could a hairdryer interfere with bluetooth frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I have a pair of Marshall IEM's that work via bluetooth. I never experience this issue aside from when I am drying my hair with a hair dryer (fan). This fan is quite large and powerful. It heats up really fast and it has a powerful rotor.

From my limited electrotechnical knowledge I got from highschool, I understand concepts such as electromagnetic induction, magnetic fields etc. I am stating this because whenever I put the hair dryer within a 5-10 CM range of my headphones, they stop working, and only the one that is close to the hair dryer stops working, not both, unless I put them one next to another. Could this be caused by electromagnetic induction?

Comment: I am talking about electromagnetic radiation ofcourse which is caused by the electromagnetic induction that happens inside of the fan itself.

Comment: In a word, "yes." Your hair dryer potentially could emit electromagnetic noise that interferes with the operation of your headphones. The fact that your headphones actually do stop working when they are brought near the running hair dryer strongly supports that conjecture. On the other hand, if those are _noise cancelling_ headphones, then that suggests another possibility. Maybe the loud noise from the hair dryer overwhelms the noise cancellation circuitry. Maybe the headphones would work if the _sound_ of the hair dryer could somehow be silenced.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have thought about the noise cancelling and I have tested it with my guitar amplifier, did not effect them. Nevertheless, I am not concerned about the safety since this is non-ionizing electromagnetic radiation. Plus, the wavelengths are wide enough to pass through my body without causing any damage. It was just a slight annoyance, wanted to make sure that it is the electromagnetic radiation coming from the hairdryer and not another effect that might be occuring.